# How could I maximize chrome browser's window using driver.manage().window() .maximize(); in a script for cross browser testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written a script for Cross Browser Testing in Selenium Webdriver using TestNG Parameters.But In this script,driver.manage().window()
.maximize(); is not working from chrome.How Could I maximize all browsers' window?

```
public class WithTestNG {   

WebDriver driver;

@Parameters("browser")
@BeforeClass

{

if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) 

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/Users/Preet/Desktop
/Path/geckodriver" );
driver = new FirefoxDriver();

}
else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie"))
{    
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\CP\\Downloads\\IED
riverServer_x64_3.4.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
}
else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome"))
{
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/Preet12/Desktop/Pa
th/chromedriver" );
driver = new ChromeDriver();    
}   
driver.manage().window().maximize();    
}

@Test(priority=0)
public void OpenStore()
{

String URL = "www.facebook.com";
driver.get(URL);

String Actual_URL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String Expected_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/";
Assert.assertEquals(Actual_URL, Expected_URL, "URL doesn't match"); 
System.out.println("URL verified");
}
```

Comment: try `options.addArguments("--start-maximized");`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

with:

```
driver.manage().window().fullscreen();
```